# How to disable CKEditor table Row-Column Add Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I am using CK inline editor, when i was add table and click on table to edit or resize, then two small table handler show on top left side of broswer.

I want to hide them or it will show close to table not on top left side of browser.

same issue on CKEditor inline demo page.
Goto http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline >> Add Table in editor >> click on table, 
Then 2 small icon appear on top left

Comment: read the docs, it is configurable

Comment: please let me know what it calls? where i find its configuration

Comment: I don't remember and I'm not going to search it for you. The documentation has a good search built in...and so does google

Comment: Thank u charli, i m not asking u, i put my problem on forum not only for u,

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `disableObjectResizing` configuration option.

Note that due to big differences in contenteditable implementation in browsers, this is *not* 100% cross-browser supported. See the note at the documentation here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disableObjectResizing

A very complicated issue, this one :)